# Error when trying to clock in agenda buffer

Tags: org-agenda

I get the following error when trying to clock into the agenda buffer.

```
byte-code: Before first headline at position 406 in buffer *Org Agenda*
```

Doesn't matter the location in the agenda buffer.  If I go to the org file `org-clock-in` works fine.  Org clock out works fine from the agenda-buffer.

This feature was working before just fine, I didn't add any new packages, or change my init file before it started, but I tried generating the agenda file off two different org files and see the same thing.

Comment: How are you trying to clock into the task from the agenda buffer? as lawlist is writing in his answer, this may be due to your not using the agenda command. Agenda commands jump to the relevant org file through stored markers in log lines (or other task related lines). Could point to the fact that you are treating the agenda buffer like a normal org buffer.

Comment: yes that was the fix

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `org-agenda-clock-in` instead of `org-clock-in`.

See:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html